# Fast C code for simple fixed-(multi)-precision operations (add, div, mul, sub)?

Tags: c, assembly, arbitrary-precision

I've been writing some cython code to implement multi-precision array operations (mostly dot products and matrix inversion) that I want to use in python.  I used mpfr as the underlying C library and by testing both in C and in Cython I find mpfr (at 200 bits precision) to be 50-200 times slower (depending on the operation) than numpy (at machine precision).  I know mpfr is very fast but i still find this overhead to be surprisingly large.  Since my needs are very limited (fixed precision, only basic operations such as add, mult, etc..) I was wondering if I could just hand-code some multi-precision operations (disregarding careful rounding, etc..).  Unfortunately this involve quite a lot of work so I was hoping to find some free code snippets in C or intel assembly for doing basic multi-precision arithmatic.  I would appreciate any references to the latter or reasons why I should or should not take this approach.

UPDATE: I should have mentioned I've already tried the QD library and its actually (slightly) slower than MPFR at similar precision (212 bits).  I guess this must be due to C++ overhead.

Comment: Comparing 200 bits precision to machine precision is comparing apples to oranges. A speed penalty of 50-200 times doesn't seem unusual to me. I doubt you'll beat it even if you only want to support "simple" operations like multiply.

Comment: I do not understand why some users are voting to close this question. What is wrong with it? The OP is using MPFR but finds it's more than s/he needs. The OP is very clear that the reason s/he is expecting that it's possible to find faster for him/her is that s/he is not using all the features MPFR offers. As it turns out, others have already felt the same need, and there even exists at least one ready-to-use alternative.

Comment: @MatthewD A double-double addition requires a few double additions to compute. If a FMA instruction is available (as found in PowerPC processors and very recent Intel/AMD desktop ones), a double-double multiplication only takes a few instructions too.

Comment: Thanks Pascal, that was exactly my reasoning.  I've seen (on another SO thread) where someone gave some CUDA assembly instructions for 128-bit operations and they claimed it was ~16 instructions so I expect that order of slowdown rather than 100-200 times.  Even using 120 bits I get a significant slowdown (60-100x).

Comment: Try profiling your program to find out which MPFR functions are using the most time.

Answer (score 4):

You could try a [double-double](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-double_arithmetic#Double-double_arithmetic) or [quad-double](http://web.mit.edu/tabbott/Public/quaddouble-debian/qd-2.3.4-old/docs/qd.pdf) library. These libraries take advantage of existing double-precision hardware for speed (I wrote a summary as part of a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853317/double-double-implementation-resilient-to-fpu-rounding-mode) of my own). There seems to be [code](http://crd.lbl.gov/~dhbailey/mpdist/qd-2.3.13.tar.gz) for the latter.

These libraries require the underlying hardware to operate **exactly** as mandated by the IEEE 754 standard. They break down if computations are made with excess precision. If you target a modern desktop processor, make sure your compiler generates SSE2 instructions for the floating-point computations. If you are stuck with 8087 instructions for some reason, you are better off using a double-double-extended library (numbers represented as the sum of two 80-bit numbers). There is one within [CRlibm](http://lipforge.ens-lyon.fr/www/crlibm/) that should come out without too much work.

---

Alternately, it may be worth trying GMP's MPF type. It could be faster since it does not try to be as nice as MPFR [according to the latter's FAQ](http://www.mpfr.org/faq.html#mpfr_vs_mpf).

Comment: I have not studied this carefully by I assume rounding issues only affect that least significant bits correct?  If so then they are mostly irrelevant to me as I just need to increase precision (beyond machine precision) but can afford to have rounding errors on the least significant bits. I actually did test QD along with MPFR and it was always _slower_ (with MPFR at 212 bits).  This is a testament to MPFRs impressive optimizations (or QD's C++ overhead).

Comment: @user2153813 Double-double or quad-double libraries do not try to provide a perfect IEEE 754-style floating-point arithmetic. In particular, one trick is to avoid renormalization on some intermediate steps, trading performances for a few bits of accuracy (the programmer needs to track the number of bits lost him/herself). This trick is used in CRlibm. Investigating your question, I found this, which suggests that GMP's MPF type **might** be faster than MPFR, since it does not try to be as nice: http://www.mpfr.org/faq.html#mpfr_vs_mpf

Comment: MPF might give a bit of an improvement but from googling the difference is maybe 20% whereas I'm looking for x3-6 speedup.  One big issue is that both MPFR and GMP use arbitrary precision so internally store the number as a pointer to an array.  Since I can fix the precision at compile time I can store the number inside a struct.  This might be very important when doing large dot products because all access will be in contiguous memory.  I want something like QD but for some reason QD is slower than MPFR.  So I'm now just looking for some C code to get me started writing my own.

Comment: To clarify the above: I want some simple baseline code to evaluate what the overhead of MPFR is to determine if its worth writing my own MP funcs which I can moreover optimize for array access (i.e. MP dot products).  I could just start with the algorithm in the qd.pdf file you pointed to but I was hoping to start from some actual code. I'll checkout CRlibm.  Thanks for all the suggestions!