# Bias value and range of the exponent of floating point

Tags: math, floating-point, precision, ieee-754

I have realized that I didn't heed duly the floating-point part of IEEE 754 standard as sitting my university desks. However, even if I'm not currently struggling with embedded stuff, I feel incompetent myself and incapable of entitling to be engineer title for lack of some way of math-calculations and wholly grasping the standard.

What I know is

- `0` and `255` are special values to express `0` and `infinity`
  values.
- There is implicit `1` to be used to express `23bit`  as `24`
- [image]
  where `e` becomes 1 only if it's `000`, if it's `111` and mantissa is `0000`, then it's infinity, and if it's `111` and mantissa is `XXXX`, then it's not a number.

What I don't understand is

- How can we mention `-126` and `127`, inclusively? How are total possible
  254 values sectioned as the inclusive values?
- Why is `127` selected as the bias value?
- Some sources explain the sectionization as `[-126..127]` but [some [-125...128]](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/IEEE-Floating-Point.html). It is really intricate and perplexing.
- How can we say the minimum `2^{-126}` if not the second aforementioned source? If it is `2^{-125}` ? (I have not be able to run my brain to get it understand till now though struggling :)
- Isn't using <s>modulo</s> remainder operator more logical with the bias value instead of subtraction i.e. `2^{e%127}`? (the correction thanks to [chux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux-reinstate-monica))

Comment: `%` is best not thought of as the _modulo operator_.  [What's the difference between “mod” and “remainder”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20638659/2410359).  `-1%127` is still -1.

Comment: "Some sources explain the sectionization as [-126..127] but some [-125...128]. It is really intricate and perplexing." --> is a question of the equation used: `1.ddd...ddd ^ 2(expo - bias)` or maybe `0.1ddd...ddd ^ 2(expo - bias)` or some other variation.  Various documentation use different notations.  In the end, it is the same range.

Comment: "Why is 127 selected as the bias value?" is a bit subjective and goes back to early IEEE development.     I think the goal was to have the range  about  logarithmically centered and not have `1.0/min_normal_number` overflow.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica what does "range logrithmatically centered" mean ?  And, what is its benefit?

Comment: There are about as many positive floating point numbers less than 1.0 as greater than 1.0.  The number system is not biased toward large nor small numbers too much.

Answer (score 1):

**Exponent range**

for 32bit float the raw exponent `rexp` is 8 bit `<0,255>` and bias is `127`. Excluding special cases `{ 0,255 }` we got `<1,254>` applying bias:

```
expmin =   1-127 = -126
expmax = 254-127 = +127
```

Denormal values are without implicit 1 so for minimal number the mantisa is `1` and if the exponent should point to lsb of mantisa then we need to shift few more:

```
expmin =   0-127-(23-1) = -149
```

Normal max value will be with maximal mantisa so:

```
max = ((2^24)-1)*(2^127) =  (2^24)*(2^127) - (2^127) = 2^151 - 2^127
```

so the real range (denormals included) of `float` is:

```
<2^-149  ,2^+151  )
<1.40e-45,2.85e+45)
```

In most specs and docs only the exponent for normalized numbers is shown so:

```
<2^-126   ,2^+127  >
<1.175e-38,1.701e38>
```

**Here a small C++/VCL example of disecting the 32 and 64 bit floats:**

```cpp
//$$---- Form CPP ----
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <vcl.h>
#include <math.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include "Unit1.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
typedef unsigned __int32 U32;
typedef __int32          S32;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// IEEE 754 double MSW masks
const U32 _f64_sig    =0x80000000;  // sign
const U32 _f64_exp    =0x7FF00000;  // exponent
const U32 _f64_exp_sig=0x40000000;  // exponent sign
const U32 _f64_exp_bia=0x3FF00000;  // exponent bias
const U32 _f64_exp_lsb=0x00100000;  // exponent LSB
const U32 _f64_exp_pos=        20;  // exponent LSB bit position
const U32 _f64_man    =0x000FFFFF;  // mantisa
const U32 _f64_man_msb=0x00080000;  // mantisa MSB
const U32 _f64_man_bits=       52;  // mantisa bits
const double _f64_lsb    = 1.7e-308;    // abs min number
// IEEE 754 single masks <2^-149,2^+151) <1.40e-45,2.85e+45).
const U32 _f32_sig    =0x80000000;  // sign
const U32 _f32_exp    =0x7F800000;  // exponent
const U32 _f32_exp_sig=0x40000000;  // exponent sign
const U32 _f32_exp_bia=0x3F800000;  // exponent bias
const U32 _f32_exp_lsb=0x00800000;  // exponent LSB
const U32 _f32_exp_pos=        23;  // exponent LSB bit position
const U32 _f32_man    =0x007FFFFF;  // mantisa
const U32 _f32_man_msb=0x00400000;  // mantisa MSB
const U32 _f32_man_bits=       23;  // mantisa bits
const float _f32_lsb     =  3.4e-38;// abs min number
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void f64_disect(double x)
    {
    const int h=1;  // may be platform dependent MSB/LSB order
    const int l=0;
    union _f64
        {
        double f;   // 64bit floating point
        U32 u[2];   // 2x32 bit uint
        } f64;

    AnsiString txt="";

    U32 man[2];
    S32 exp,bias;
    char sign='+';
    f64.f=x;
    bias=_f64_exp_bia>>_f64_exp_pos;

    if (f64.u[h]&_f64_sig) sign='-';
    exp   =(f64.u[h]&_f64_exp)>>_f64_exp_pos;
    exp  -=bias;
    man[h]=f64.u[h]&_f64_man;
    man[l]=f64.u[l];

        if (exp==-bias  )           // zero, denormalized
        {
        exp-=_f64_man_bits-1;       // change exp pointing from msb to lsb (ignoring implicit bit)
        txt=AnsiString().sprintf("%c%06X%08Xh>>%4i",sign,man[h],man[l],-exp);
        }
    else if (exp==+bias+1)          // Inf,NaN
        {
        if (man[h]|man[l]==0) txt=AnsiString().sprintf("%cInf                  ",sign);
         else                 txt=AnsiString().sprintf("%cNaN                  ",sign);
        man[h]=0; man[l]=0; exp=0;
        }
    else{
        exp   -=_f64_man_bits;      // change exp pointing from msb to lsb
        man[h]|=_f64_exp_lsb;       // implicit msb mantisa bit for normalized numbers
        txt=AnsiString().sprintf("%06X",man);
        if (exp<0) txt=AnsiString().sprintf("%c%06X%08Xh>>%4i",sign,man[h],man[l],-exp);
         else      txt=AnsiString().sprintf("%c%06X%08Xh<<%4i",sign,man[h],man[l],+exp);
        }

    // reconstruct man,exp back to double
    double y=double(man[l])*pow(2.0,exp);
          y+=double(man[h])*pow(2.0,exp+32.0);
    Form1->mm_log->Lines->Add(AnsiString().sprintf("%21.10lf = %s = %21.10lf",x,txt,y));
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void f32_disect(double x)
    {
    union _f32      // float bits access
        {
        float f;    // 32bit floating point
        U32 u;      // 32 bit uint
        } f32;

    AnsiString txt="";

    U32 man;
    S32 exp,bias;
    char sign='+';
    f32.f=x;
    bias=_f32_exp_bia>>_f32_exp_pos;

    if (f32.u&_f32_sig) sign='-';
    exp =(f32.u&_f32_exp)>>_f32_exp_pos;
    exp-=bias;
    man =f32.u&_f32_man;

        if (exp==-bias  )           // zero, denormalized
        {
        exp-=_f32_man_bits-1;       // change exp pointing from msb to lsb (ignoring implicit bit)
        txt=AnsiString().sprintf("%c%06Xh>>%3i",sign,man,-exp);
        }
    else if (exp==+bias+1)          // Inf,NaN
        {
        if (man==0) txt=AnsiString().sprintf("%cInf         ",sign);
         else       txt=AnsiString().sprintf("%cNaN         ",sign);
        man=0; exp=0;
        }
    else{
        exp-=_f32_man_bits;         // change exp pointing from msb to lsb
        man|=_f32_exp_lsb;          // implicit msb mantisa bit for normalized numbers
        txt=AnsiString().sprintf("%06X",man);
        if (exp<0) txt=AnsiString().sprintf("%c%06Xh>>%3i",sign,man,-exp);
         else      txt=AnsiString().sprintf("%c%06Xh<<%3i",sign,man,+exp);
        }

    // reconstruct man,exp back to float
    float y=float(man)*pow(2.0,exp);
    Form1->mm_log->Lines->Add(AnsiString().sprintf("%21.10f = %s = %21.10f",x,txt,y));
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--- Builder: --------------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner):TForm(Owner)
    {
    mm_log->Lines->Add("[Float]\r\n");

    f32_disect(123*pow(2.0,-127-22));   // Denormalizxed
    f32_disect(+0.0);                   // Zero
    f32_disect(-0.0);                   // Zero
    f32_disect(+0.0/0.0);               // NaN
    f32_disect(-0.0/0.0);               // NaN
    f32_disect(+1.0/0.0);               // Inf
    f32_disect(-1.0/0.0);               // Inf
    f32_disect(+123.456);               // Normalized
    f32_disect(-0.000123);              // Normalized

    mm_log->Lines->Add("\r\n[Double]\r\n");

    f64_disect(123*pow(2.0,-127-22));   // Denormalizxed
    f64_disect(+0.0);                   // Zero
    f64_disect(-0.0);                   // Zero
    f64_disect(+0.0/0.0);               // NaN
    f64_disect(-0.0/0.0);               // NaN
    f64_disect(+1.0/0.0);               // Inf
    f64_disect(-1.0/0.0);               // Inf
    f64_disect(+123.456);               // Normalized
    f64_disect(-0.000123);              // Normalized

    mm_log->Lines->Add("\r\n[Fixed]\r\n");
    const int n=10;
    float fx=12.345,fy=4.321,fm=1<<n;
    int   x=float(fx*fm);
    int   y=float(fy*fm);
    mm_log->Lines->Add(AnsiString().sprintf("%7.3f + %7.3f = %8.3f = %8.3f",fx,fy,fx+fy,float(int((x+y)   ))/fm));
    mm_log->Lines->Add(AnsiString().sprintf("%7.3f - %7.3f = %8.3f = %8.3f",fx,fy,fx-fy,float(int((x-y)   ))/fm));
    mm_log->Lines->Add(AnsiString().sprintf("%7.3f * %7.3f = %8.3f = %8.3f",fx,fy,fx*fy,float(int((x*y)>>n))/fm));
    mm_log->Lines->Add(AnsiString().sprintf("%7.3f / %7.3f = %8.3f = %8.3f",fx,fy,fx/fy,float(int((x/y)<<n))/fm
                                                                                       +float(int(((x%y)<<n)/y))/fm));
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Which might help you understand a bit more ... If you're interested then look also at this:

- [print 32bit float using only integer arithmetics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59861545/2521214)

**exponent bias**

It was selected as midle between the range edges:

```
bias = (0+255)/2 = 127
```

to simply have the same range for positive and negative exponents as possible

**modulo**

using `exp=rexp%127` will not give you negative values from unsigned `rexp` no matter what not to mention division is slow operation (at least at the time the specs was created)... That is why `exp=rexp-bias`

Answer (score 1):

> How can we mention `-126` and `127`, inclusively? How are total possible 254 values sectioned as the inclusive values?

IEEE 754-2008 3.3 says *emin*, the minimum exponent, for any format shall be 1−*emax*, where *emax* is the maximum exponent. Table 3.2 in that clause says *emax* for the 32-bit format (named “binary32”) shall be 127. So *emin* is 1−127 = −126.

There is no mathematical constraint that forces this. The relationship is chosen as a matter of preference. I recall there being a desire to have slightly more positive exponents than negative but do not recall the justification for this.

> Why is `127` selected as the bias value?

Once the bounds above are selected, 127 is necessarily the value needed to encode them in eight bits (as codes 1-254 while leaving 0 and 255 as special codes).

> Some sources explain the sectionization as `[-126..127]` but some `[-125...128]`. It is really intricate and perplexing.

Given bits of a binary32 that are the sign bit S, the eight exponent bits E (which are a binary representation of a number *e*), and the 23 significand bits F (which are a binary representation of a number *f*), and given 0 < *e* < 255, then the following are equivalent to each other:

- The number represented is (−1)<sup>S</sup> • 2<sup>*e*−127</sup> • (1+*f*/2<sup>23</sup>).
- The number represented is (−1)<sup>S</sup> • 2<sup>*e*−127</sup> • 1.F<sub>2</sub>.
- The number represented is (−1)<sup>S</sup> • 2<sup>*e*−126</sup> • (½+*f*/2<sup>24</sup>).
- The number represented is (−1)<sup>S</sup> • 2<sup>*e*−126</sup> • .1F<sub>2</sub>.
- The number represented is (−1)<sup>S</sup> • 2<sup>*e*−150</sup> • (2<sup>23</sup>+*f*).
- The number represented is (−1)<sup>S</sup> • 2<sup>*e*−150</sup> • 1F.<sub>2</sub>.

The difference between the first two is just that the first takes the significand bits F, treats them as a binary numeral to get a number *f*, then divides that number by 2<sup>23</sup> and adds 1, whereas the second uses the 23 significand bits F to write a 24-bit numeral “1.F”, which it then interprets as a binary numeral. These two methods produce the same value.

The difference between the first pair and the second pair is that the first prepares a significand in the half-open interval [1, 2), whereas the second prepares a significand in the half-open interval [½, 1) and adjusts the exponent to compensate. The product is the same.

The difference between the first pair and the third pair is also one of scaling. The third pair scales the significand so that it is an integer. The first form is most commonly seen in discussions of floating-point numbers, but the third form is useful for mathematical proofs because number theory generally works with integers. This form is also mentioned in IEEE 754 in passing, also in clause 3.3.

> How can we say the minimum `2^{-126}` if not the second aforementioned source? If it is `2^{-125}` ? (I have not be able to run my brain to get it understand till now though struggling :)

The minimum positive normal value has S bit 0, E bits 00000001, and F bits 00000000000000000000000. In the first form, this represents +1 • 2<sup>1−127</sup> • 1 = 2<sup>−126</sup>. In the second form, it represents +1 • 2<sup>1−126</sup> • ½ = 2<sup>−126</sup>. In the third form, it represents +1 • 2<sup>1-150</sup> • 2<sup>23</sup> = 2<sup>−126</sup>. So the form is irrelevant; the values represented are the same.

> Isn't using remainder operator more logical with the bias value instead of subtraction i.e. `2^{e%127}`?

No. That would cause the exponent field values 1 and 128 to map to the same value, and that would waste some encodings. There is no benefit to that.

Additionally, the encoding format is such that all positive floating-point numbers are in the same order as their encodings: Increasing the encoding increases the value represented, and vice-versa. This relationship would not old with any sort of wrapped interpretation of the exponent field. (Unfortunately, this is flipped for negative numbers, so compare the encodings of floating-point numbers as pure integers does not give the same results as comparing the floating-point numbers.)