# How to square any non-integer number without pow() and multiplication?

Tags: c, math, floating-point

I want to replace pow with something other than multiplication. How can i do it?
THIS PROGRAM SEARCHES FOR THE ROOT OF THE SUM OF SQUARES OF ENTERED NUMBERS:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define N 10000
double norm2(double a[],int n);
int main(void)
{
    double a[N]; int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    norm2(a,n);
    
    return 0;
}
double norm2(double a[],int n)
{
    int i=0; double sum=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%le",&a[i]);
        if(a[i]<0.0) a[i]=-a[i];
        sum+=exp2(2*log2(a[i]));}
    printf("%le",sqrtf(sum));
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I guess you could square anything with repeated addition.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this?

Comment: `exp(log(x)+log(x))` is equivalent to square

Comment: i want square numbers as 1.2162e+5 and without loss of accuracy

Comment: @EmanuelP Would be tricky for fractional numbers.

Comment: i try now,mr stark

Comment: "and without loss of accuracy" You can't.

Comment: mr stark, i love you, thanks you very much and others for taking the time to help me

Comment: yes, i already understand)

Comment: @WithOrxan But I hope you do understand that this method is like scratching the left ear with the right heel?

Comment: @EugeneSh.  The customer is always right.

Comment: @stark Yet a proper disclaimer should be stated :)

Comment: yes i know, but my teacher wants this ) If you know any other methods,please,write

Comment: "i want square numbers as 1.2162e+5 and without loss of accuracy" and `exp(log(x)+log(x))` leads to precision loss versus  the direct `x*y`.  You have 2 goals in conflict.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica `sqr` alone is losing precision as `x*x` needs twice the mantissa bits ...

Comment: If [log/exp pow approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19072451/2521214) is not an option I would use binary long multiplication instead of repeated addition ... you know if you got to compute `sqr(10^50)`  it would take a long time to compute with repeated addition...  the binary version will be just `O(1)` with 24 or 53 iterations depending on if used `float` or `double` ... this might help [Bias value and range of the exponent of floating point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65390554/2521214) with separating mantisa/exponent for the computations.

Comment: Also see [Power by squaring for negative exponents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30962495/2521214) for some ideas ...

Comment: @Spektre If we were talking about integers, "sqr alone is losing precision as x*x needs twice the mantissa bits" makes some sense regarding absolute precision, but here, `x` is a FP.  `x*x` incurs up to 0.5 ULP of _relative precision_ loss.  `log(x)` and `exp()` each incur losses on the order of 1.0 ULP.   Using `log2(x)` and `exp2()` would help a bit, yet an exponential approach is problematic when `x <= 0.0`.

Comment: With Orxan, in the end, code does `sqrt(sum)` and except for select values, will not meet "without loss of accuracy".  Every `*, +=` step, unless we resort to some extended arithmetic type,  incurs an accuracy loss.  The goal "without loss of accuracy" in fundamentally unobtainable, even if code could used `*`.  Please clarify realistic accuracy/precision goals.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yes I know the lossless computation of sqr is not achievable no matter what multiplication is used (that is what my comment was all about) btw. the doubling the mantissa bits is true also for non integer numbers. Also If you remember we both already dealt with [`(x<0)^(y)` problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67089172/2521214) just few days so `log,exp` approach is usable even then (but not as easily)...

Comment: How can i solve problem , when i enter 2 numbers in program in description : 3.e165 and 4.e165 , why program print me 0?

Comment: you mean n=2 and then `3.e165 , 4.e165 ` ... I do not like this `if(a[i]<0){a[i]*=-1;}` better would be `if(a[i]<0.0) a[i]=-a[i];` back to the problem my bet is that `e165` is too big number once you `sqr` it overflows the `double`  limit `~e308` ... as the result simply do not fit into double anymore as `165+165>308` ...

Comment: And the fact that we then select the root does not play a role?

Comment: what root? you are squaring ... `(3.e165)^2 = 9.e+330` which is bigger than max representable double value (appart of `+inf`) so the result of your `exp2` is overflowing ... if you compute `3.e165*3.e165` directly it will also overflow ...

Comment: yes, and how i can change program that this program work(without long double)

Comment: @WithOrxan by using bignum lib or by implementing such datatype yourself ... however usually minor change in computation can lead to usable number ranges ... so what exactly for you need this ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the method of squaring using repeated addition as suggested by @EmanuelP

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    char *len;
    double f = strtod(argv[1],&len);
    char * pos = strchr(argv[1],'.');

    if (f <= 0.0 || pos == NULL) {
        printf("Invalid input. %p\n",pos);
        return -1;
    }
    int n = f;                 // integer part
    int frac = atoi(pos+1);    // fractional part
    printf("Int part %d, frac part %d\n",n,frac);
    /* Add integer times */
    double square = 0.0;
    while(n--)
        square += f;
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < (len -pos-1); i++)
        f /= 10.0;
    /* add fractional times */
    while (frac--)
        square += f;
    printf("%s %f\n",argv[1],square);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define N 10000
double norm2(double a[],int n);
int main(void)
{
    double a[N]; int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    
    printf("norm =%le",norm2(a,n));
    return 0;
}
double norm2(double a[],int n)
{
    int i=0; double sum=0,maxe,x;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    scanf("%le",&a[i]);
    maxe=fabs(a[0]);
    for( i = 1; i < n; i++)
        if (maxe < fabs(a[i])) maxe = fabs(a[i]);
    for( i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        x = a[i]/maxe;
        sum += x*x;
    }
    return maxe*sqrt(sum);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: "without pow() and multiplication" does not allow this answer's `x*x` and `maxe*sqrt(sum)`.